# Media Player force landscape

Tags: ios, swift, landscape

In my app I want a video to open in landscape mode when the MediaPlayer is being opened, but I don't want to enable landscape in all other ViewControllers. How can I programmatically achieve this using Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare method `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` in your view controller, and change frame relatively to your needs.
In more detail, you need to read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIContentContainer/viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:), at least.